# $G$ either has a $K_4$ or an independent set of size $3$

Tags: graph-theory, proof-writing

I have to show the following claims:

A simple graph $G$ with $|V(G)|\ge 6$ either has a $K_3$ or an independent set of size $3$.

A simple graph $G$ with $|V(G)|\ge 14$ either has a $K_4$ or an independent set of size $3$.

For the first one we consider vertex $x \in V(G)$. Then $x$ has $5$ options to have neighbors and by Pigeonhole Principle vertex $x$ has  at least $3$ neighbors or at least $3$ nonneighbors. If any of its neighbors share an edge then we have a $K_3$, otherwise we get an independent set of size $3$. I think this is correct.

How should I begin to do the second one? Can it be done in a similar way?

Comment: This is *Ramsey theory*.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I agree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the general strategy of the first statement, as well as the first statement itself, to prove the second statement. Also, you should be able to get away with $|V(G)| \geq 10$ in the second question.

Really you’re doing the first steps in inductively proving these kinds of things.

Comment: I find it difficult to prove that it has a $K_4$...

Comment: @mandella can you explain more how you’re thinking of starting the proof?

Comment: As the first case, we choose a vertex $x$ and it has $13$ possible  neighbors so at least $6$ neighbors and at least $7$ not neighbors. If there are at least $7$ not neighbors then we have an independent set of size $3$...

Comment: Amongst its neighbors we wish to find a $K_3$ or an independent set of size 3; amongst its non-neighbors, we wish to find a $K_4$ or an independent set of size 2...

Comment: for among its neighbors, we could use first part.

Comment: Precisely. Now the amongst its non-neighbors part should be easy. How many vertices do you need it both parts?

Comment: Among its non-neighbors if none are adjacent then we have an indep. set of size 2..